# How to make <div> border size same as <p>?

Tags: html, css

I have getting difficult to make height border of `<div>` same as `<p>`

This is my code:

```css
div.relative {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

p.parag {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #A3AD11;
}
```

```html
<h2>position: relative;</h2>

<p>An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position:
</p>

<div class="relative">
  <p class="parag">
    This div element has position: relative;</p>
</div>
```

I just made width same but I don't know how to make for height.
This is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbed6c6d/)

Comment: Clearly write questiob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p>` tag has margins by default. You need to remove them like so:

```css
div.relative {
position:absolute;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
p.parag {
position:relative;
border: 3px solid #A3AD11;
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h2>position: relative;</h2>

<p>An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal 
position:</p>

<div class="relative"><p class="parag">
This div element has position: relative;</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;float:none;"></div>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table-cell`

```css
div.relative {
 
    position:absolute;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    display:flex;
    display:table-cell;
   
}
p.parag {
    position:relative;
    border: 3px solid #A3AD11;  
    display:table-cell;
   
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>position: relative;</h2>

<p>An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position:</p>

<div class="relative"><p class="parag">
This div element has position: relative;</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;float:none;"></div>
</body>
```

Or you can give the `<p>` tag a margin of 0, like so:

```css
div.relative {
    position:absolute;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    display:flex;
}
p.parag {
    margin: 0;
   position:relative;
    border: 3px solid #A3AD11;
   
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>position: relative;</h2>

<p>An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position:</p>

<div class="relative"><p class="parag">
This div element has position: relative;</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;float:none;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
margin: 0 0 0 0;
```

to p.parag

Answer (score 0):

Sample Image:

[image]

If you want something like attached image then you have to simply do this:

```
p.parag {
  margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    border: 3px solid #A3AD11;

}
```